# How to add a field default to bulk user records

Tags: entities, users, views

I've added a field to the user profile page, and set the default. I can see that when I create a new user, the default is set, however for existing users the field is empty.

Is there a way to apply the default to all existing user records?

I've tried View Bulk Operations, but that didn't seem to have an action to update a field.

I'm about to write the mySQL script to update the field, but surely there is a better way........

Comment: Have you tried "Change Value" on that field via VBO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the answers to this question: [Bulk field update?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2426/bulk-field-update) In particular the answer suggesting "Execute Arbitrary PHP Script".

(Looks like a duplicate.)