# Editing new fields in old content

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I have an existing content type that I would like to add a field to. However, after I've added the field in my development version of the site the field is not present when editing old content. On new content the field is available for editing.

I have entries in the `field_data_field_content_field` table from following the steps in  [Bulk field update?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2426/bulk-field-update) (using `EntityFieldQuery`, `entity_load`, and `entity_save`). The values are usable by the node object, whether it was by viewing the node manually or loading it with `entity_load`. When viewing the node the field also appears in the `$content` array, but is not rendered even though I have not called `hide()` on it. It still does not show up as an option when I attempt to edit the node through Drupal.

Is there a proper way to nudge existing instances of a content type to use this new field in its edit form, or should I be manually re-making the old instances of the affected content types?

Comment: I discovered that the problem was that I was attempting to edit the field with an different user than the original author. After nudging the node so that it would be owned by me, I was able to edit the field.

I'm still not certain of how I made this field like this, but since it is going in a different direction than my original post I will re-post the issue as a separate question.

Comment: Discovered that the main cause of my problem was that I had overlooked the Field Permissions module. The account that I was testing in did not belong to a role with the permission to administer field permissions or view the private fields of content created by another user.