# How can I update all content of a content type with a newly added field?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I have a content type with a set of fields.

Hundred(s) of pieces of content have been created from this content type.

I recently had to go back and add a new field to the content type.

In order for all content of that content type that I previously created to show the newly added field, I have so far been going into each piece of content and adding in the field. This is going to take forever.

Is there another tool or process I can use to update all previously created content with the new field added to the content type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Step 1

Use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to create a Rules Component, which includes whatever Rules Conditions you might need (if any), and with a Rules Action to **Set a data value**, for each of those fields you want to be updated.

#### Step 2

Create a view of the nodes for which those fields should be added. Then transform that view into a view that uses [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations), and use the technique documented in "[How to use Rules to create a custom bulk operation for a VBO view?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/88)". In doing so, you'll then be able to use the Rules Component from Step 1.

#### Tutorial

To get the idea, have a look at the video about [Using Rules components with VBO](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/using-rules-components-with-vbo)" which uses a Rules Component with (only) 1 parameter. If you want even more, then also watch the subsequent "[Using Rules components with more than one parameter](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/using-rules-componens-with-more-than-one-parameter)" video.

Attention: to process like 100.000 entities at once is quite a challenge (memory requirements, etc). Therefor you might want to also watch the video about "[More details about VBO settings](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/more-details-about-vbo-settings)" ... Before you are tempted to use VBO for processing them all at once ...

Comment: @lcunning merci for the accept (and +1)!

Answer (score 1):

if I understand correctly you need to update node in range of new date? right? so if this is the case why not use EntityFieldQuery() to list of this nodes then node_save() or field_attach_update() to update the new value.

if this is the case I'd be happy to give you some snippets to help you do this.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) for this.  You can make a quick view to select the content with a modify action to set the value.  No programming needed.

VBO is a great tool to keep handy for a lot of stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

Existing Question, Please refer the below link

As they mention use Devel module to Run PHP code.

[Bulk Field Update](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2426/bulk-field-update)